# Description of NSDictionary - why are some key names with quotes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

I used a simple NSLog on a dictionary:

```
NSLog(@"dict %@", dictionary);
```

the result was:

```
...
"first_name" = Peter;
gender = male;
id = 1171548848;
"last_name" = Lapisu;
...
```

**Why are some key names in "quotes" and some not?**

Comment: this is just a visual representation of the keys for the output, you should not worry about it because when you want to refer any key, you will use the `@"MyKeyInDictionary"` format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the string has characters apart from alphabets + numerics, it will quote the string.

This is the basic methodology of the `description` function.